# Oracle Select Query optimization

Tags: database, oracle, select

I ‘m executing some sql statements on my data and I have the following situation.

Select statement looks like this

```
select *
from t1, t2
where t1.id = t2.t1_id
t1.c1 = 'X' and t1.c2  in ('Y', 'Z')
```

Running the explain plan I saw that the col2 filtering has cost 11 (Table Access with filter predicates) and the col1 1 (table access index).

How can I reduce the cost of the searching on col2? Should I put any hint in my query?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please paste the explain plan into the question.

Comment: ... And the real query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the ANSI syntax for queries:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id
where t1.c1 = 'X' and t1.c2  in ('Y', 'Z');
```

Consider an index on `t1(c1, c2, id)` and `t2(t1_id)`.  The first index should be used to get the rows from `t1`.  The second should speed up the join to `t2`.

EDIT:

As per David's comment, an index on `t1(c1, c2)` might perform slightly better.

Comment: With the select * getting all columns from both tables, the index on t1 might as well be (c1, c2) I think.

Comment: @DavidAldridge . . . That is an interesting point.  It is possible (but I do not *know*) that with the `id` in the index, the index alone would be used for the join with the additional columns coming later.  However, Oracle might fetch the pages first and then do the join.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would access the table first, but whichever way it does I think that the net work would be lower without the id on the index -- you'd also get a more compact index, and COMPRESS might be useful as well.